# Finding missing items in an int list

Tags: python, algorithm, performance

Here is a problem I am trying to solve: trying to find missing photographs from a sequence of filenames. The problem boils down to: given an unsorted list of integers, return a sorted list of missing numbers. Below is my code.

What I am looking for are:

- Are there more efficient algorithms?
- Is there any performance problem if the list is large (tens of thousands)
- Corner cases which does not work?

  ```
  def find_missing_items(int_list):
      '''
      Finds missing integer within an unsorted list and return a list of 
      missing items

      >>> find_missing_items([1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 10])
      [3, 4, 8, 9]

      >>> find_missing_items([3, 1, 2])
      []
      '''

      # Put the list in a set, find smallest and largest items
      original_set  = set(int_list)
      smallest_item = min(original_set)
      largest_item  = max(original_set)

      # Create a super set of all items from smallest to largest
      full_set = set(xrange(smallest_item, largest_item + 1))

      # Missing items are the ones that are in the full_set, but not in
      # the original_set
      return sorted(list(full_set - original_set))

  if __name__ == '__main__':
      import doctest
      doctest.testmod()
  ```

Comment: Looks fine to me. `find_missing_items([-20000,0,20000])` returned correctly all 39998 items in less than 2s running on a old dual-core.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For this

```
full_set = set(xrange(smallest_item, largest_item + 1))
```

I'd suggest inlining the min and max:

```
full_set = set(xrange(min(original), max(original) + 1))
```

You don't need to convert to a list before using sorted so:

```
sorted(list(full_set - original_set))
```

Can be written as:

```
sorted(full_set - original_set)
```

Comment: Beautiful. I especially like the last one: sorted() without list().